# Tomcat and Matlab Compiler Runtime Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, matlab, tomcat, memory, jvm

I have Tomcat 7 and MCR 8.3 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server.
When the server receive few connections I have no problem, but when they are too much, I have an Out of Memory Error.
The JVM args are:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp
```

The error in the log is:

```
Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2756), pid=27165, tid=140664871548672
```

The Heap is free

```
    Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1289728K, used 672681K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007fde00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1288704K, 52% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007d3b6a578,0x00000007f9500000)
  from space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000007f9500000,0x00000007f9500000,0x00000007f9600000)
  to   space 37376K, 0% used [0x00000007fb980000,0x00000007fb980000,0x00000007fde00000)
 ParOldGen       total 128000K, used 64279K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000707d00000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 128000K, 50% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000703ec5d98,0x0000000707d00000)
 PSPermGen       total 262144K, used 45159K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006d0000000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 262144K, 17% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c2c19fc8,0x00000006d0000000)
```

and the system memory is free, too:

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 32904520k(26875548k free), swap 999420k(999420k free)
```

What could be?

This is the line in my setenv.sh file:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -d64 -Xms128m -Xmx8192m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
```

Comment: Aren't you using too big xmx? isn't it 32 bit jre? it could be that it can't allocate more than 2gb

Comment: isn't there a log like hs_err_pid27165.log? might be this http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-cassandra-user/201409.mbox/%3CCAD_Xd-+i4dA=CQ4Nty7hFy3Hcz7VHJ0XnjeCfcRtCtjyTKZJkg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: @MarianP that thread speaks about Cassandra... I use a 64 bit JRE... I update with the JAVA_OPTS line in my setenv.sh file.

Comment: Which JVM version are you using? anything else in the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. It was NOT a configuration problem. I didn't deallocate the memory from matlab function. Shame on me...